# Processing HTTP headers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a AWS Lambda function in Python 3 that evaluates the headers of an incoming HTTP request but I can only find examples about making requests. Can I do what I want with the boto or some other library?

For context I'm trying to do this https://hackernoon.com/serverless-password-protecting-a-static-website-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-bfaaa01b8666

Comment: The post you are referencing is for Lambda@Edge, which is a Lambda extension for CloudFront that [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-lambda-function-configuration) that the Lambda function be written in Node.JS.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thought I'd be able to use any of the runtime environments.

Comment: Is your Lambda function behind an API Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried API Gateway with AWS Lambda for handling your HTTP requests? Maybe this is what you are looking for :[API Gatway with AWS Lambda Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-create-lambda-backend)